# how to export without drop shadow in sketch

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

I am new to sketch. After designed an icon in sketch, I want to export it to PNG. The icon is drawn with multiple path and grouped together. But when I export it, the exported image has drop shadow in it. I don't want the shadow. Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Answer (score -2):

You can try icongroup `Layer>Flatten Selection to Bitmap`. And then `Make Exportable`.